# Script para alterar nomes das tabelas no banco de dados PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Tenho esse script:

```
SELECT 
n.nspname AS schema_name, 
c.relname AS table_name, 
c.reltuples::int AS num_reg 
FROM pg_class c 
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
    LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace t ON t.oid = c.reltablespace 
WHERE c.relkind = 'r'::char 
AND nspname NOT IN('information_schema','pg_catalog','pg_toast')
```

Quero adicionar a letra 's' ao final de cada tabela que retorna o script em um banco de dados PostgreSQL. Como proceder? Alguém poderia dar uma ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um bloco de código anônimo através da cláusula `DO`, resumidamente é uma function que não pode ter retorno e não é preciso gravar um objeto no banco de dados.

Na function será realizado um `loop` no resultado da consulta SQL e para cada tupla será executado o comando para renomear a tabela.

```
do $$
declare
    tables record;
begin
    for tables in
        SELECT 
            n.nspname AS schema_name, 
            c.relname AS table_name, 
            c.reltuples::int AS num_reg 
            FROM pg_class c 
                LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
                LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace t ON t.oid = c.reltablespace 
            WHERE c.relkind = 'r'::char 
            AND nspname NOT IN('information_schema','pg_catalog','pg_toast')
    loop
        execute format('alter table %I.%I rename to %Is;', tables.schema_name, tables.table_name, tables.table_name);
    end loop;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-do.html

Comment: muito obrigado! deu certo

Comment: blz @leoCastro, como resolveu seu problema não esquece de marcar como melhor resposta. vlw!